# Is it OK to always reset serial to avoid caps after bulk upsert in postgres?

Tags: postgresql

Say I've a table

```
create table test (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  name text unique
);
```

I wonder if this is OK (always reset the serial after `insert into ... on conflict...` to avoid caps):

(code below may be executed cocurrently for I'm writing a orm lib for a general purpose for bulk upsert)

```
begin
insert into test (name) values (('foo'),('bar')...) on conflict(name) do update set name=excluded.name;
SELECT setval('test_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) from test));
end;
```

Background: I've a regular scripts which may upsert many rows every 1 minutes. It turns out soon that `id` becomes 220k+ while there are only 100+ rows in table. I don't want to run out of ids.

Or could I use a method like this one([from here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17267423/2803340)). It seems no conflicts possible when inserting:

```
BEGIN;

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE newvals(id integer, somedata text);

INSERT INTO newvals(id, somedata) VALUES (2, 'Joe'), (3, 'Alan');

LOCK TABLE testtable IN EXCLUSIVE MODE;

UPDATE testtable
SET somedata = newvals.somedata
FROM newvals
WHERE newvals.id = testtable.id;

INSERT INTO testtable
SELECT newvals.id, newvals.somedata
FROM newvals
LEFT OUTER JOIN testtable ON (testtable.id = newvals.id)
WHERE testtable.id IS NULL;

COMMIT;
```

For some reasons, I don't want to use uuid.

Comment: "*I don't want to run out of ids*" - use a `bigint`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name but still I wordereing...